# I edited the background context menu in regedit to "open power shell here", how do I make it open as an admin?

Tags: powershell, windows-10, admin, regedit

Value data: powershell.exe -admin -noexit -command Set-Location -literalPath '%V'

-admin causes the powershell to close because it is not recognized. My question is how do I make powershell open as adminstrator from the context menu?

I tried this function as per another stackoverflow answer, to test as to see whether I am running as admin:

```
function Test-Administrator  
{  
    $user = [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent();
    (New-Object Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal $user).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltinRole]::Administrator)  
}


Test-Administrator

(it prints false)
```

Comment: this appears to be what you are seeking ... windows 10 - Add 'Open Powershell here as admin' option to folder context menu - Super User — https://superuser.com/questions/1014208/add-open-powershell-here-as-admin-option-to-folder-context-menu

Comment: Thank you for the answer

Comment: you are most welcome! glad to have helped a little ... [*grin*]